# How can I view the exact values I generated in my Barplot/plot?

Tags: r

So I have a Barplot using the basic barplot function. But I want to know the exact y values from the plot I generated. Is there a way to do this? This is my graph:

[image]

Comment: do you mean the x values? the y is just the height of the bars from your input. barplot returns the x-coordinates invisibly, `bp <- barplot(...); bp`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide data so I cant help you specifically, but you can use the `text()` function to add values in base R. You can try playing around with your specific data to fit your needs, or share your data and I can modify the answer.

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(name = letters[1:5],
                   value = sample(1:100,5))

a <- barplot(height=data$value, names=data$name)
text(a, data$value/2, labels = data$value)
```

[image]

Or if you have a stacked barplot like in your image:

```
data <- data.frame(A = 1:5,        # Create example data
                   B = 6:2,
                   C = 3,
                   D = c(3, 5, 1, 1, 2))


cumdata <- apply(data, 2, cumsum)

a <- barplot(as.matrix(data))

text(unlist(data), 
     x = rep(a, each = nrow(cumdata)), 
     y = unlist(cumdata-data/2))
```

[image]